# Error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a text file in python but I keep getting the same error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: /home/briannagopaul/testdata.txt
```

I've made sure that the path exists using `realpath` on cmd. It exists and the above path that I've used is from this command. I've also tried `"/home/briannagopaul/Datasets/testdata.txt"`(the file is in a folder called Datasets, but this produces the same error.

This is what I've been trying:

```
f = open('/home/briannagopaul/testdata.txt')
print(f)
```

Comment: Is this an absolute filepath, or a relative filepath from the folder where your script is being run?

Comment: Did you try `open(os.path.realpath('/home/briannagopaul/testdata.txt'))`?

Comment: Thank you so much i love u man

Answer (score 0):

I would open cmd and get into the folder that your text file is in. Then, you can do "pwd" on cmd and get correct path.

Comment: Did you try going into your file and copying the exact wording by clicking rename then coping it, and getting the path by going into properties and copying it?